# New tag for the Fall of the Roman Empire

Tags: discussion, tags

I've made two questions about Attila on History StackExchange, and only found two suitable tags for them: **ancient-history** and **roman-empire**.

I'm wondering if a **fall-roman-empire** tag (or something like that) would be useful and welcome to the site.

Comment: Depending on the content, those might also benefit from [tag:steppe-nomads] or [tag:central-asia].

Comment: Damn, I didn't knew the steppe-nomads tag existed. But - although I foresee a fall of the roman empire tag full of steppe nomads - steppe-nomads could be also applicable to Genghis Khan or Timur. Also, I imagine there's a lot of users specialized in the fall of roman empire. Nonetheless, very good point, sir.

Comment: Maybe, [tag:fall-of-rome]?

Comment: @T.E.D. We have a new fall of rome question for which those tags do not apply. Maybe a new tag is in order after all?